# Should we have a "weekly puzzle"?

Tags: discussion, chat

I was thinking of ways we could further engage community members, existing and new, and I had a thought: maybe we should run a 'weekly puzzle' chat event?

This could be a good forum for discussion of questions that may not necessarily be on-topic on the site for being too broad, or could be a forum for riddles and other logic puzzles.

What types of puzzles would you be interested in seeing? Would you even like to have this at all?

Answer (score 7):

I'm in favor of a regular puzzle chat event. If nothing else, it will help get people into chat, which will help keep the site going strong.

Answer (score 1):

If it would encourage *discussion about* the puzzle at hand, and *discussion about* the solution/solutions offered, and not become simply "here's a puzzle, race to answer it first!", then I see that it could well have value.

It could take the form of a cryptic crossword (perhaps a few clues from recent editions of *The Times*), or working through some sudoku layouts, or chess positions, or IQ puzzlers - varying between different types of puzzle would help to keep it vibrant and attract different people.

Most of those, of course, could well be in danger of falling into the category of "poor question" if simply asked on the main site, but a discussion about them in the chat environment could well work.